# Using Java JVM -xdump argument to print http wire data

Tags: java, ibm-jvm

I am using the `IBM JRE`, and I have a `Java SDK` which is used by 2 clients: A Java client, as well as a .NET client.

On the Java client, I use the following settings to capture http data:

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump","true");
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump","true");
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump","true");
System.setProperty("HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
```

In the .NET client, I can pass on parameters to the JVM.
Are there parameters that I can use which achieve the same behavior as the `System.setProperty` settings in the Java client?

I researched a bit about dump agents etc, but couldn't seem to find something suitable.
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.60%2Fdiag%2Ftools%2Fdump_agents.html

Answer (score 0):

If the arguments are passed to the JVM then it could not be done via setProperty API. JVM reads the arguments meant for JVM during initialization phase and obey as per the instructions provided so it is not possible set JVM arguments during runtime.